# Webflux not inserting infos in my Atlas MongoDB (Cluster)

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-webflux

I'm watching a course that's we are creating an API Rest with Spring Webflux with MongoDB Cluster (atlas).
The course is outdates because the teacher was used the mLab that's now is a part of the MongoDB.

Well, I got the connection without any erros but when I try to add the collection "playlist" with some strings that's not working and my console dont show any erros.

Here is my console when I run the application

https://i.stack.imgur.com/phHPJ.jpg

There's the code:

DummyData.java

```
package com.apirest.webflux;

import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;

import com.apirest.webflux.document.Playlist;
import com.apirest.webflux.repository.PlaylistRepository;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

public class DummyData implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final PlaylistRepository playlistRepository;

    DummyData(PlaylistRepository playlistRepository) {
        this.playlistRepository = playlistRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        playlistRepository.deleteAll().thenMany(Flux.just("API REST Spring Boot", "Deploy de uma aplicação java no IBM Cloud", "Java 8", 
                "Github","Spring Security", "Web Service RESTFULL", "Bean no Spring Framework")
                .map(nome -> new Playlist(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), nome)).flatMap(playlistRepository::save))
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

WebfluxAppllication.java

```
package com.apirest.webflux;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class WebfluxApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebfluxApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Playlist.java

```
package com.apirest.webflux.document;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document
public class Playlist {

    public Playlist(String id, String nome) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String nome;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

}
```

PlaylistRepository.java

```
package com.apirest.webflux.repository;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.ReactiveMongoRepository;

import com.apirest.webflux.document.Playlist;

public interface PlaylistRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Playlist, String> {
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem go be missing an `@Component` on your `DummyData` class. The command line runner is not started if spring cannot find it. The rest of your code looks fine.